# Homebrew installed PostgreSQL could not connect, database files are incompatible with server

Tags: postgresql, psql, mac-os-x

Here's the error message I'm getting today when I attempt to log in to my localhost PosgreSQL databases using `psql`:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew and this morning I've uninstalled and reinstalled using that utility, with no change observable.  The `psql` client works fine, and I can still use it to connect to databases over the network.  I only connect to my local databases once every month or two, and it worked fine before, so I'm assuming this is due to some automatic update but I don't know which.  Mac OS upgraded itself to High Sierra (10.13) recently.

The same error message popped up on here in 2014 ([link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory)) but that was a case where a guy had trouble starting the server.  In my case I believe it's running -- I've used `brew services start postgresql` and yes, I've restarted a few times today.  However, the file mentioned in the error, `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`, does not exist on my system.  I think this is a case of some configuration mistake.  Anyone have a clue how to fix?

Update: I tried starting the server manually (as recommended by Evan) and I think I made a breakthrough. Here's the error I get when I try to start it manually:

```
FATAL: database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.6, which is not compatible with this version 10.1.
```

Update 2: Ultimately I solved this problem by replacing my data directory and re-initializing it with an empty database using `initdb` as in the answer marked "correct".  To be fair, all three answers were helpful.  I was unable to update the database from the old version to the new one because I no longer had the binaries for the older version of Postgres.

Comment: Assuming Postgres is running on 5432, does specifying the host make a difference? eg. `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d postgres`. `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` exists on my mac (still on Sierra, fwiw), but I also started it using `pg_ctl -D $DATADIR start`, not via the `brew services start` command.

Comment: Is the only PostgreSQL installed on your system through `brew`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't have any data, then it seems like a problem with Brew. Did you run `brew` upgrade, there are [two answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17822974/124486) that address this, I've merged both of them together to try the best of both worlds.

1. Backing up

   ```
   launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
   sudo mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/.postgres_bak;
   ```
2. Making sure you have the latest version

   ```
   brew update
   brew upgrade postgresql
   ```
3. **Either, not both** reinitialize or try to upgrade your data-dir

   1. Nuke it (start from scratch, leaving the old back up)

      ```
      initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
      ```
   2. Try to upgrade it

      ```
      pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/$myOldVersion/bin/ -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/$myNewVersion/bin -d /usr/local/var/.postgres_bak -D /usr/local/var/postgres
      ```
4. Restart server.

   ```
   brew services start postgresql
   ```
5. Delete the backup, if the server restarts and everything works remove the backup

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/.postgres_bak
   ```

Comment: Ultimately I went with "nuke it" because the old version binaries were no longer present.

Comment: You got a typo in `/usr/local/bar/.postgres_bak;`. Should be `/usr/local/var/.postgres_bak;`. I'm too annoyed by the SO validation wanting me to edit more than 6 chars so I won't try to work around it and leave a comment instead

Comment: thank you for this post, nuke it was the way to go +42

Comment: Saw a detailed explanation on this blog https://olivierlacan.com/posts/migrating-homebrew-postgres-to-a-new-version/

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you haven't run `brew cleanup postgresql` yet. `brew info` gives all the relevant info, including if you still have the previous version and the fact you might need to run `pg_upgrade` (shortened output below).

This will tell you what version your db is on: `cat /usr/local/var/postgres/PG_VERSION`

If you didn't mean to upgrade to PostgreSQL 10.1, and assuming your previous version is 9.6.6, this could be enough: `brew switch postgresql 9.6.6`

If you need to reinstall an older version, this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/279726

It looks like the data directory is **`/usr/local/var/postgres`** by default (as I haven't changed mine), see last line of output below.

```
$ brew info postgresql
postgresql: stable 10.1 (bottled), HEAD
[...]
==> Caveats
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html

  You will need your previous PostgreSQL installation from brew to perform
  `pg_upgrade` or `pg_dumpall` depending on your upgrade method.

  Do not run `brew cleanup postgresql` until you have performed the migration.

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
$
```

But if you do want to use 10.1, basically you could run *something like* this, still assuming you were running 9.6.6 before (change directory name based on your actual *previous* PostgreSQL version). Run **one** command at a time and check the output before proceeding with the next:

```
mv -i /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres96
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.6/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.1/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres96 -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

See here for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/pgupgrade.html

```
********************************************************
* PLEASE MAKE BACKUPS BEFORE DOING ANY OF THE ABOVE!!! *
********************************************************
```

The funny thing is, if I try to install the latest PostgreSQL I get:

```
$ brew install postgresql
Error: postgresql 9.5.5 is already installed
To upgrade to 10.1, run `brew upgrade postgresql`
```

So I'm not sure how you got from 9.6.x to 10.1 without seeing that message...

Comment: Oh I've been through at least a few version upgrades before this one, that didn't give me the current error.  I'll try your recommendations.

Comment: Problem: the binaries for 9.6.6 (or any old version) don't exist on my system, and the `pg_upgrade` command doesn't work without the `-b` argument.  I probably used `brew uninstall` and `brew install` a few times in trying to troubleshoot this problem.  Am I stuck?  If I just want to start over with an empty local server, how would I do that?

Comment: If you need to reinstall an older version, this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/279726

Comment: How is "nuke it" a better answer, when I gave you options to reinstall 9.6.6? Meh

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have any other version of PostgreSQL installed, or just the one from brew?
- Is the server itself running for you connect to it check `sudo ps aux`?
- Are you connecting to the right port. Check `netstat` see [this awesome post by Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101962/124486).
- Do you use brew to upgrade to a new version of PostgreSQL? If so you may want to check out this [hella-popular question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

You may also want to see this post, and [start the server manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975660/124486).

Comment: (1) just the one from brew (2) no! that's odd (3-4) skipped these ones... (5) I tried that and I think I made a breakthrough.  Here's the error I get when I try to start it manually: `FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2017-12-06 14:35:33.309 EST [1318] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.6, which is not compatible with this version 10.1.`

Comment: @Joe `sudo updatedb; sudo locate postgres | grep bin`

Comment: updatedb gets me a `command not found` error

Comment: 'locate' finds only one postgres on my system, and it's v.10.1 in /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.1/

Comment: looks like there's a utility called `pg_upgrade` ... it needs my data directory, how do I know where that is?

Comment: @Joe do you have any data yet?